# Sum function in CTE recursive in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
Month    | Value1  | data    | Excel formula
---------+---------+---------+--------------
March-19 | 30 (B2) | 30 (C2) | = (B2)-sum(0) 
April-19 | 30 (B3) |  0 (C3) | = (B3)-sum(C2) 
May-19   | 30 (B4) |  0 (C4) | = (B4)-sum(C2:C3)
June-19  | 30 (B5) |  0 (C5) | = (B5)-sum(C2:C4)
```

We need to calculate the c column that is DATA column. Formula for calculating the data column is present in Excel formula. Any cell value of data column == (is value of a fixed column- sum of all the previous values of that calculated column).

Basically we need to use CTE recursive with the sum function.

How can we do that?

Comment: Are your really storing dates as `'March-19'`, `'April-19'`, or you are using a legitimate `date`-like datatype?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need recursion here, window functions should do it:

```
select
    t.*,
    value1 - sum(data) over(
        order by month
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) res
from mytable t
```

This assumes that you are storing dates in the `month` column in a `date`-like datatype (or at least in a string format that is properly sortable).

We can also express the query as follows, without a range clause:

```
select
    t.*,
    value1 + data - sum(data) over(order by month) res
from mytable t
```

Comment: Yes data is stored in the date format. Though I can use this format also to do the increments. Let me check your answer once and will revert back But thanks for such a quick reply.

Comment: Interesting - has not seen that SQL syntax before. Is that specific only to SQL Server?

Comment: @JGFMK: no that's quite standard syntax for window functions.

Comment: @JGFMK . . . The second query does what you want.  For the first, you need to handle `NULL` values which needlessly complicates the expression.